# Creating subplots from multiple text files in a loop

Tags: matplotlib, python-3.5, subplot

So I have been trying to load text files onto multiple subplots but the plots always seem to come up as one text file. Can anyone point me into the right #direction as to how to go about this?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

RiverData1 = np.loadtxt('Gray1961.txt', skiprows = 2)

RiverData2 = np.loadtxt('Hack1957.txt', skiprows = 2)

RiverData3 = np.loadtxt('Rignon1996.txt', skiprows = 2)

RiverData4 = np.loadtxt('Robert1990.txt', skiprows = 2)

RiverData5 = np.loadtxt('Langbein1947_p145.txt', skiprows = 2)

RiverData6 = np.loadtxt('Langbein1947_p146.txt', skiprows = 2)

RiverData7 = np.loadtxt('Langbein1947_p149.txt', skiprows = 2)

RiverData8 = np.loadtxt('Langbein1947_p152.txt', skiprows = 2)

plotnums = 1    

for plotnums in range (1,9):
    plt.subplot(2,4,plotnums)
    plt.plot((RiverData1[:,0]), (RiverData1[:,1]),'ko') 
    plt.plot((RiverData2[:,0]), (RiverData2[:,1]),'ko')
    plt.plot((RiverData3[:,0]), (RiverData3[:,1]),'ko')
    plt.plot((RiverData4[:,0]), (RiverData4[:,1]),'ko')
    plt.plot((RiverData5[:,0]), (RiverData5[:,1]),'ko')
    plt.plot((RiverData6[:,0]), (RiverData6[:,1]),'ko')
    plt.plot((RiverData7[:,0]), (RiverData7[:,1]),'ko')
    plt.plot((RiverData8[:,0]), (RiverData8[:,1]),'ko')
    plt.xlabel('River Length (km)')
    plt.ylabel('Area (Km$^2$)') 
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.yscale('log')
    plotnums=plotnums+1

    plt.show()
```

Comment: remove the `plotnums=plotnums+1` in the for loop

Answer (score 1):

I suggest loading the data inside the loop as well. Additionally, you should capture the axis-handle in a variable to control which axis is used for plotting the data. To avoid any data artifacts, I suggest setting the variables to `None` at the end of each iteration.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# store your file names in a list to be able to iterate over them:

FILES = ['Gray1961.txt','Hack1957.txt','Rignon1996.txt',\
         'Robert1990.txt','Langbein1947_p145.txt','Langbein1947_p146.txt',\
         'Langbein1947_p149.txt','Langbein1947_p152.txt']

# specify desired conversion factors for each file, separated by x and y

xFactor =[1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00\
          2.59, 2.59, 2.59, 2.59]

yFactor = [1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000\
           1.609, 1.609, 1.609, 1.609] 

# loop through all files;
# range(len(FILES)) returns a list of integers from 0 to 7 in this example

for n in range(len(FILES)):

    # load the data from each file:

    RiverData = np.loadtext(FILES[n], skiprows = 2)

    # convert the data per the specified factors:

    X = [xi * xFactor[n] for xi in RiverData[:,0]]
    Y = [yi * yFactor[n] for yi in RiverData[:,1]]

    # create sub-plot, here, you need to use n+1,
    # because your loop iterable counts from 0,
    # but your sub-plots count from 1

    ax = plt.subplot(2,4,n+1)

    # use the created axis object to plot your data;
    # use ax.plot instead of plt.plot 

    ax.plot(X, Y,'ko') 

    # specify your axis details, again use ax.plot instead of plt.plot

    ax.set_xlabel('River Length (km)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Area (Km$^2$)') 

    # the file name can be used as plot title
    # (if you want to omit the .txt ending, use [:-4] 
    # to omit the last for characters in the title string)

    ax.set_title(FILES[n][:-4])
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    ax.set_yscale('log')

    # to avoid surprises going from one loop to the next,
    # clear the data from the variables

    RiverData = None
    ax = None

plt.show()
```

---

As [Thiru pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308431/creating-subplots-from-multiple-text-files-in-a-loop#comment60240937_36308431) you do not need to increment your iterable inside a `for`-loop.

Comment: Thanks Schorsch, very big help. Is there a way to plot the different file names above each subplot in order, as they all appear as Gray1961.

Comment: Thanks Schorsch, very big help. I have an issue being that each file is composed of an x (area in km^2) and y(length=km), which is the case for the first 4 files. However the last four files (landgbein files) area is in (miles^2) and length is in (miles). Ive tried multiplying this by a conversion factor (x2.59 for miles^2 to get to km^2) and (x1.609 for miles to km). but have not been able to get this working in the loop you described before.    Is there a way to plot the different file names above each subplot in order, as they all keep appearing with Gray1961!!

Comment: @Milo see changed code block. If this answer helped you, consider upvoting it, by clicking on the upper triangle at the upper left corner of the answer (above the `1`). [You can even consider accepting it, by clicking on the checkmark below the `1`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the matplotlib documentation on subplots

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/subplots.html

You can create a figure and add multiple subplots to it.

```
fig = plt.figure()
for plotnums in range(1,9):
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(2,4,plotnums) # update the numbers as required
    ...
```

Comment: I am able to plot the 8 subplots fine individually. The problem is assigning each text_file to one of the the 8 individual subplots, via a loop.